# Passagem de parametro pelo modular

Tags: flutter, dart

Não estou sabendo passar o parâmetro do arquivo `home_page` para o arquivo `produtos_module` quando o usuário clicar.

**arquivo home_page.dart**

```
Observer(
       builder: (_) {
         List<CategoriaModel> categoria = controller.categoria.data;
         return Container(
           height: 160,
           width: larguraTela,
           margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
             vertical: 20,
           ),
           child: ListView.builder(
             itemCount: categoria.length,
             scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
             itemBuilder: (_, index) {
               var model = categoria[index];
               return CategoriaWidget(
                 nameCategoria: model.titulo,
                 icon: "assets/images/icons/${model.icon}.svg",
                onTap: () {
                   Modular.to.pushNamed(
                     RoutersConst.produtos,
                     arguments: CategoriaModel(
                       titulo: model.titulo,
                     ),
                   );
                 },
               );
             },
           ),
         );
       },
     ),
```

**arquivo produtos_module.dart**

```
   class ProdutosModule extends ChildModule {
   @override
   List<Bind> get binds => [
         Bind((i) => ProdutosController(i.get())),
         Bind<IProdutoRepository>(
          (i) => ProdutoRepository(Firestore.instance, "Beer"), // pegar a categoria quando o usuario clicar 
         ),
       ];
 
   @override
   List<Router> get routers => [
         Router(
           RoutersConst.produtos,
           child: (_, args) => ProdutosPage(),
         ),
       ];
 
   static Inject get to => Inject<ProdutosModule>.of();
 }
```

**arquivo produto_repository.dart**

```
   class ProdutoRepository implements IProdutoRepository {
  final Firestore firestore;
  final String categoria;

  ProdutoRepository(this.firestore, this.categoria);

  @override
  Stream<List<ProdutoModel>> getProdutos() => firestore
      .collection("produtos")
      .snapshots()
      .map((query) => query.documents
          .map((doc) => ProdutoModel.fromDocument(doc))
          .toList());
  @override
  Stream<List<ProdutoModel>> getProdutoCategoria() => firestore
      .collection("produtos")
      .where("categoria", isEqualTo: categoria)
      .snapshots()
      .map((query) => query.documents
          .map((doc) => ProdutoModel.fromDocument(doc))
          .toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No click do item da home_page você está fazendo certo. Mas você não vai passar o parâmetro para o `ChildModule` mas sim para a classe vinculada ao `routers`.

Faça a implementação corretamente no Modulo e na classe que será chamada, deverá ficar assim:

```
   class ProdutosModule extends ChildModule {
   @override
   List<Bind> get binds => [
         Bind((i) => ProdutosController(i.get())),
         Bind<IProdutoRepository>(
          (i) => ProdutoRepository(Firestore.instance, "Beer"), // pegar a categoria quando o usuario clicar 
         ),
       ];
 
   @override
   List<Router> get routers => [
         Router(
           RoutersConst.produtos,
           child: (_, args) => ProdutosPage(dados: args.data),
         ),
       ];
 
   static Inject get to => Inject<ProdutosModule>.of();
 }
```

E na sua classe `ProdutosPage` ajustes ela para receber o parâmetro

```
class ProdutosPage extends StatelessWidget {

    ProdutosPage({this.dados});
    
    CategoriaModel dados;

}
```

**DICA**

Dar uma lida na documentação do package não mata ninguém [flutter_modular](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular#dynamic-routes).

Comment: Obrigado <3, desculpa pelo incomodo